# Как составить регулярку для 301 редиректа?

Tags: .htaccess

Пример 1) с этого `https://site.ru/catalog/vegs/potatos/?PAGEN_1=2`
на этот `https://site.ru/catalog/vegs/potatos/pagen2/`

Пример 2) с этого `https://site.ru/catalog/furniture/table/?PAGEN_1=3`
на этот `https://site.ru/catalog/furniture/table/pagen3/`

Пока вот это сделал, правило вообще не понимаю как сделать

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?PAGEN_1=([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1pagen%1/ [L]
```

$1 - ссылка на захваченную группу в RewriteRule

%1 - ссылка на захваченную группу в последнем RewriteCond

Comment: Не работает, циклическое перенаправление

Comment: смотрите другие рулы и настройки редиректов в своем битриксе